# perl - use split or regular expression to get directory names from text file

Tags: perl

I have a text file that has a list of directory names like this:

```
drwxr-x---   - test_hd open_review          0 2011-10-31 14:17 /proj/open_review/20111030
drwxr-x---   - test_hd open_review          0 2011-11-01 16:10 /proj/open_review/20111031
drwxr-x---   - test_hd open_review          0 2011-11-02 17:12 /proj/open_review/20111101
```

I want to extract the directory to include "/", like "/proj/open_review/20111030" in another file.

I would like to learn this in perl vs. using cut. Would it be better to use a split or a regex for this? Can someone give me a good example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ perl -lane 'print $F[-1]' input.txt > output.txt
```

**Explanation**

- `-a`

  autosplit, defaults to splitting line on whitespaces, so if your path contains spaces the command won't work
- `-l`

  automatic line-ending processing, so you don't have to explicitly `chomp` when reading or add a `"\n"` when printing
- `-n`

  read input.txt in line-by-line
- `print $F[-1]`

  prints the last element of the `@F` array, which is generated when the line (stored in `$_`) is [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)
- `>`

  shell redirection

See [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more information on Perl command-line switches.

Answer (score 3):

You use split() when you want to say what to skip. You use a regex when you want to say what to keep. You use substr() (or unpack) on fixed-width data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $fname = substr $_, 63;
    print "$fname\n";
}

__DATA__
drwxr-x---   - test_hd open_review          0 2011-10-31 14:17 /proj/open_review/20111030
drwxr-x---   - test_hd open_review          0 2011-11-01 16:10 /proj/open_review/20111031
drwxr-x---   - test_hd open_review          0 2011-11-02 17:12 /proj/open_review/20111101
```

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, we prefer modules over ad-hoc regex. See [File::Listing](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aListing).

```
use File::Listing qw(parse_dir);
print $_->[0], "\n" for parse_dir <<'LS';
drwxr-x---   - test_hd open_review          0 2011-10-31 14:17 /proj/open_review/20111030
drwxr-x---   - test_hd open_review          0 2011-11-01 16:10 /proj/open_review/20111031
drwxr-x---   - test_hd open_review          0 2011-11-02 17:12 /proj/open_review/20111101
LS
```

---

```
/proj/open_review/20111030
/proj/open_review/20111031
/proj/open_review/20111101
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to capture the path with regex:

```
\d+:\d+\s(.*[^\s])
```