# perl one line script to get last record with path

Tags: perl

Can someone help me with a perl one liner to get the following? It has to be in perl.

```
drwxr-x---   - abc_grid abc_fltr          0 2012-02-05 23:24 /samples/abc/accounts/filtered/20120204
drwxr-x---   - abc_grid abc_fltr          0 2012-02-12 14:31 /samples/abc/accounts/filtered/20120211
drwxr-x---   - abc_grid abc_fltr          0 2012-02-19 14:31 /samples/abc/accounts/filtered/20120218
drwxr-x---   - abc_grid abc_fltr          0 2012-02-29 00:24 /samples/abc/accounts/filtered/20120225
drwxr-x---   - abc_grid abc_fltr          0 2012-03-05 11:36 /samples/abc/accounts/filtered/20120303
```

I want the last record and the path.

```
/samples/abc/accounts/filtered/20120303
```

Comment: Parsing output from `ls` is less than ideal. I'm sure you can get a much better answer if you ask about your main problem, rather than the problems with your solution.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883091/perl-use-split-or-regular-expression-to-get-directory-names-from-text-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're golfing, then

```
ls -l|perl -lane 'END{print $F[-1]}'
```

can be shortened to

```
ls -l|perl -lane'END{print$F[-1]}'
ls -l|perl -lane'}{print$F[-1]'
ls -l|perl -lane}{print\$F[-1]
ls -l|perl -anE}{say\$F[-1]
```

---

Here's an ungolfed solution that doesn't use `ls`. More reliable that way anyway.

```
perl -E'say(( sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } @ARGV )[0])' \
    /samples/abc/accounts/filtered/*
```

Ref: [`-M`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Comment: @JRFerguson, This answer is for your benefit.

Comment: It wasn't Perl golf but the elimination of an unnecessary `tail` process.  Nevertheless, I appreciate the golf :-)

Comment: @jdamae, Updated to be a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls -l|perl -lane 'END{print $F[-1]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ne 's/^.* //; $last = $_; END { print $last; }'
```

Answer (score 2):

[perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) `-a`:

```
   ls -l | tail -1 | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that what you want is the fully-qualified path name of the most recently-modified file from the /samples/abc/accounts/filtered directory.  That's going off of your example above.  Feel free to correct me if that's not right.

With your "pure Perl" restriction, you can use...

```
perl -e '$d="/samples/abc/accounts/filtered";print +(sort { -M "$a" <=> -M "$b" } glob("${d}/*"))[0], "\n"'
```

But I think in this case I'd just use the shell...

```
ls -1dt /samples/abc/accounts/filtered/* | tail -1
```